# Validation logic best practices and design patterns

Tags: java, validation, design-patterns

I have a class that performs some sort of (potentially redundant) validation logic on some number of arguments in the functions it contains. To demonstrate, I have the following `Controller` and `ValidationHelper` classes:

```
class ValidationHelper {
    void validateA(int a, String b) { /*...*/ }

    void validateB(int c, double d, String e) { /*...*/ }

    void validateC(int f) { /*...*/ }
}

class Controller {
    private ValidationHelper helper;

    void foo(int a, String b, int f) {
        this.helper.validateA(a, b);
        this.helper.validateC(f);
        // .. Rest of foo
    }

    void bar(int a, String b, int c, double d, String e) {
        this.helper.validateA(a, b);
        this.helper.validateB(c, d, e);
        // .. Rest of bar
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to improve this validation architecture so any addition in validation logic wouldn't be as intrusive as the current implementation, and have validation become much cleaner? If this isn't achievable, would you have any suggestions if all the functions had the exact same validation statements? (e.g. both `foo()` and `bar()` containing ONLY `this.helper.validateA(a,b)`):

```
class Controller {
    void foo(int a, String b, int f) {
        this.helper.validateA(a, b);
        // .. Rest of foo
    }

    void bar(int a, String b, int c, double d, String e) {
        this.helper.validateA(a, b);
        // .. Rest of bar
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ValidationHelper` is a code smell. You should be skeptical of any class ending in -ER.

I would implement this using validating [decorators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Your example is a bit vague with all of the random meaningless variables, so let me invent my own.

```
interface CoffeeMachine
{
    Coffee brew(Volume water, Volume milk);
}

class DarkRoastCoffeeMachine implements CoffeeMachine
{
    public Coffee brew(Volume water, Volume milk) {
         return new Coffee(Roast.DARK, water, milk);
    }
}
```

But what if we want to enforce some constraints? Let's say there must be at least some quantity of water - we can't make coffee without water.

```
class WaterEnforcingCoffeeMachine implements CoffeeMachine
{
    private CoffeeMachine delegate;

    public WaterEnforcingCoffeeMachine(CoffeeMachine delegate) {
         this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public Coffee brew(Volume water, Volume milk) {
         if (water.millilitres() < 50) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must use more than 50ml of water");
         }
         return delegate.brew(water, milk);
    }
}
```

You can then compose these like so:

```
CoffeeMachine coffeeMachine = new WaterEnforcingCoffeeMachine(
    new DarkRoastCoffeeMachine()
);
```

Need additional validation? Add another decorator.

Comment: "You should be skeptical of any class ending in -ER". Controller?

Comment: @BrianAgnew Yes. MVC is a good pattern but not for OOP. Controllers break encapsulation.

Comment: I would argue that they enforce encapsulation if written properly (using observers, perhaps, even though they end in -er too :-)

Comment: @BrianAgnew I've yet to see an MVC framework that was implemented in a way that was conducive to that idea. Spring certainly isn't. Observable/Observer isn't inherently bad, but the names are. Source and Target are better.

Comment: The decorator pattern would work well for the second scenario I talked about - if the entire class follows an identical set of validation steps I can imagine it'd be helpful. But in reality (the first scenario) in which a specialized `CoffeeMachine` is needed for each function, I don't see how that would help in reducing code. In fact, the code base will blow up as we add more functions that require different permutations of validation steps.

Comment: @ddolce I never said it would reduce the amount of code. You didn't ask for that. You asked for a better architecture and this is it. Your code is purely procedural. This is OO.

Comment: @Michael sorry, I should've worded it differently. What i meant was that the decorator pattern wouldn't help in my case for the reason I stated in the comment above - it wouldn't offer much benefit but would incur the cost of adding a lot of code to the class (one unique coffee machine needed for every function). The original point of my question is to ask for a way to elegantly use some sort of design pattern to achieve the purpose of permuting validation steps without blowing up the code base.

Comment: @ddolce "it wouldn't offer much benefit" It does though. It has the benefit of not being procedural. Each decorator is a proper object which respects the single responsibility principle. It's more maintainable and more testable. It separates validation logic from business logic. There isn't any design pattern which matches what you are after. Validating decorators are the best way to do validation.

Comment: I also don't get why people downvoted this question - I think this question is legitimate, genuine, and not a duplicate. Yes how the controller was implemented might not be the textbook OO way, but we're all here to learn and be curious, downvoting and calling to close a question because the code involved isnt structured the way you want it to be, is bad taste and quite frankly, rude.

Comment: @ddolce I didn't downvote anything so I don't know why you're complaining to me. If you want me to speculate as to why, it might be because your example is confusing.